# JavaObjectModel. What is it?

Tags: java, xml

Simply stated : What is a Java Object Model. I want to create one for a XML file. I am sure it is different than the Java Application. SO what is it.
Obviously, i tried google but to my surprise didnot get any specific or clear answer.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, why do you want to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object model is a set of classes (with their properties and methods) used to represent a particular collection of information. A Java object model is simply an object model in which the language used to describe those classes is Java. If you want to create a Java object model for an XML file, then you need to analyze what information is held in your XML file and design Java classes to represent the same information. There are tools that can automate this process, though the representation they come up with will not always be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I guess an Object Model is some java POJO whose properties reflect the structure of the xml file you are parsing.

A "simple" way to achieve this transformation is to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#About%20JAXB).

Answer (score 1):

Any model is essentially the way you represent data. So your Java Object Model is your data represented as Java Objects. An XML Model would be your data represented as XML. JSON is your data represented as JavaScript "Objects", etc.